# Running sonar analysis on maven project fails due to CVS folders

Tags: maven, cvs, sonarqube

I'm evaluating Sonar to analyse my project. When I run the sonar goal with "mvn sonar:sonar" I get the following exception:

"Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar ... The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration"

The mentioned Java file in this error is "../foo/bar/CVS/Base/MyClass.java".

Although this is part of my source directory this is a file created by the CVS system and in my opinion should be ignored by the sonar analysis. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Tested again with a fresh version from CVS and there are no such "duplicate" Java files in CVS/Base folder and everything is working well.

Comment: CVS does not keep copies of files under the CVS folder. The only things in there are metadata files (eg. `Entries`, `Repository`). Is it possible that some other process copied files into there or that you did it by accident?

Comment: Maybe Eclipse is doing this when working with different versions or branches. As I said I tried to run Sonar for evaluation purposes on my workspace project which probably is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't correctly specified the properties in your POM, CVS files should never be considered as source code.

Answer (score 0):

Of courses sources were not configured well.

But also specifically to specify CVS, one can use property like

```
sonar.scm.provider=cvs
```